# How to show test coverage reports for successful TFS builds

Tags: tfs-2015, vnext

Is it possible and if so, how to have TFS display jasmine test results?  I am successfully creating jasmine test reports using the plato npm package on the server during a build although I'm yet to link the report to the TFS build success page in TFS.  Can someone please advise how this is possible?

Many thanks!!

**Update**

Initial comments refer to looking at the following link although I think this is a general link in TFS as opposed to a link relative to the "current" build.

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/get-started/node

I have a build definition that cleans, compiles and runs jasmine tests and using plato (npm install plato) creates a html report on the server.  I want developers looking at the build to be able to open the report for the build that they're looking at.  Please confirm is the suggested extension link is still applicable because I've tried it just now without success.

Please advise.

**Update**

I've successfully included NUnit tests to be executed in our build, shown in the screen shot.  I want to have a similar feature for Jasmine.  The second screen shot shows the report page the Plato package produces for Jasmine tests.  I would like this available within the TFS results page.

**Screenshot #1 - NUnit test results (as seen in TFS)**

[image: nunit results screen shot in TFS]

**Screenshot #2 - Plato produced jasmine results report**

[image: jasmine report generated]

This reported is generated on the server in a build definition step.

Comment: Can you provide the details of your requirement? You can provide the screenshot of what it likes.

Comment: I've updated my question with screenshots, I am looking for something like the second screen shot to be available within the successful build page.  Anything would be a good start, i.e. number of tests, name of tests, how many tests etc..

Comment: let me know if you need anything else.  Many thanks,

Comment: You can do it through extension, the simple way is that you can send the request (HTTP) to get Plato produced jasmine results report (Screenshot #2) and display the response result to the HTML page of build result extension.

Comment: okay great, can you provide steps to do this please?  I tried making an extension but I wasn't sure what to do.

Comment: What's the result if you try to build the build result extension (refer to the sample that I provided)?

Comment: I'll try that tonight and let you know!  Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom section in build result through extension, with this way, you can add the link in that custom section.

There is the sample about build result extension:

[vsts-extension-samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-extension-samples/tree/master/build-results-enhancer)

More information about how to build extension, you can refer to this article (apply to on premise TFS)

[Create your first extension for Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/get-started/node)

Answer (score 0):

You can use tampermonkey to inject a link into TFS.  The following will work.  (It's horrible but I haven't achieved the same result with any "proper" approach).

**Example script**

```
  (function() {
      'use strict';
      setTimeout(function() {
          $(".pivot-view.pivot-tabs").append("<li><a href='plato-report.html' target='_blank'>Jasmine tests</a></li>");
      }, 3000);
  })();
```

[https://tampermonkey.net](https://tampermonkey.net/) (for chrome)

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-gb/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/ (for firefox)